# How to fetch multiple rows from fire store and display in Data Table --FLUTTER

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, error-handling, data-retrieval

**I have a collection on firestore named "CASHOUT" having fields Random1,2 and 3.**
[image: Document 1 of Collection CASHOUT]

**which I am able to fetch and display successfuly in Data table widget**

[image]

**But when I created another document with same fiels**
[image]

**It throws me an error of

> rows.cells.length != columns.length

**

[image]

**What I'm doing wrong?? Here is the code**

```
            StreamBuilder(
              stream: _firestore.collection('CASHOUT').snapshots(),
              builder: (BuildContext context,
                  AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.hasError) {
                  return const Text('Something went wrong');
                }

                if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                  return const Text("Loading");
                }

                if (snapshot.hasData) {
                  List<DataCell> displayedDataCell = [];

                  for (var item in snapshot.data!.docs) {
                    displayedDataCell.add(
                      DataCell(
                        Text(
                          item['RANDOM1'].toString(),
                        ),
                      ),
                    );
                    displayedDataCell.add(
                      DataCell(
                        Text(
                          item['RANDOM2'].toString(),
                        ),
                      ),
                    );
                    displayedDataCell.add(
                      DataCell(
                        Text(
                          item['RANDOM3'].toString(),
                        ),
                      ),
                    );
                  }

                  return FittedBox(
                    child: DataTable(
                      columns: const <DataColumn>[
                        DataColumn(
                          label: Text(
                            'Date',
                          ),
                        ),
                        DataColumn(
                          label: Text(
                            'Amount',
                          ),
                        ),
                        DataColumn(
                          label: Text(
                            'Optional Detail',
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                      rows: <DataRow>[
                        DataRow(cells: displayedDataCell),
                      ],
                    ),
                  );
                }
                return const CircularProgressIndicator();
              },
            ),
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting this error because you are creating one `DataRow` with 6 items in it's cell and instead you have to create 2 `DataRow` with 3 cells.

```dart
rows: <DataRow>[
  for (int i = 0; i < displayedDataCell.length; i += 3)
    DataRow(cells: [displayedDataCell[i], displayedDataCell[i + 1], displayedDataCell[i + 2]])
],
```

Answer (score 1):

while you are adding the data to the displayedDataCell you are adding different rows a single horizontal data to the table causing you this error.

a number of data in listed in a row must match the number of the column.
so instead of creating a list of data cell just add a row for every data in the DataTable row

first get the data

```
Map<String, dynamic> data = document.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
```

then replace your row of data table with this then it will auto update

```
                  <DataRow>[
                        DataRow(
                          cells: <DataCell>[
                            DataCell(
                              Text(
                                item['RANDOM1'].toString(),
                              ),
                            ),
                            DataCell(
                              Text(
                                item['RANDOM2'].toString(),
                              ),
                            ),
                            DataCell(
                              Text(
                                item['RANDOM3'].toString(),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ],
```